# CSV file row average in C

Tags: c, csv, average, stdio

I have a CSV file with 5 rows and 10 columns (each row containing 10 elements in form of decimals).
I need to write a program that opens and reads the file and takes the average of each row .

```
void exercise3(){
     FILE* Khoa_file=fopen("beeap20_knows_coding.csv", "r");  // attempt to open the file
    double sum , ave; //making decimal varibales
    int i;    //i as int to to use for the sum calculation

    if (Khoa_file==NULL){    //if the file opens nothiing (eg. not found)
        perror("Error while opening file");     // print this as error
    }
    while(1){                  //while true
        int s;         // variable in which content of file will be saved in
        while((s=fgetc(Khoa_file)) !='\n' && s != EOF){   /*while loop, the idea was to use fgets to make a while loop . The fgets was supposed to take in data until it ecounters '\n', 
                                                            then that would be 1 row and the next while loop would do the same thing (5x in total), but didnt work...*/
            printf("%c", s);   // print out the "gotten" values 
        }
        if(s == EOF)
            break;    // when reaching the end of the file break out of the loop 
        printf("\t");
         sum = 0;
        while(1==fscanf(Khoa_file, "%d%*c", &i)){//%*c skip ',' and '\n'   
            sum += i;

        }
        ave = sum / 10 ;
        printf("the average %f\n", ave);
    }
    fclose(Khoa_file);
}
```

This is what i attempted, but it is complete garbage. Please help..

Comment: Could you explain what's happening and why it's wrong? "Complete garbage" is slightly unclear. Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Just do something like:

```
int val[10];
while( 10 == scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d ", val, val + 1, val + 2 ...) ){
...
}
```

Although looking through your code it looks like your input is comma separated, so you may prefer:

```
while( 10 == scanf("%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%d ", ...
```

This does not verify that the input is 10 data entries per line, but it does work if your input follows the convention that each line has only 9 commas.  Also, it will work on input like "5,\n6,..." where 10 data points span multiple lines.  Remove the whitespace in the format string as desired. If you care about having a precise input format and want to validate the occurrences of the newlines, you could either use `fgets` or replace the trailing space in the format string with `%c` and validate that scanf reads an explicit `\n`.  But simply structuring your while loop to read 10 data elements at a time with one `scanf` will probably be sufficient for your needs.